# I/O error on non-existent device?

Tags: linux, centos, lvm, io, dev

Getting the following in /var/log/messages:

```
Sep 17 10:38:53 server1 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 0
Sep 17 10:38:53 server1 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 63
Sep 17 10:38:53 server1 kernel: end_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 208845
```

In addition, any time an lvm utility runs, before the results are returned (properly), the following is shown:

```
/dev/sde: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
/dev/sde1: read failed after 0 of 2048 at 0: Input/output error
/dev/sde2: read failed after 0 of 2048 at 0: Input/output error
```

`fdisk -l` does not show such a device and returns no errors.  Also nothing in `mount` or `fstab`. I can't find anything about this device, other than its listing in `/dev` and the errors show above. This is a live server, I would rather not have to resort to a reboot if it can be avoided.

*CentOS 5.5 , LSI hardware SAS RAID , dual quad-core Xeon, 16GB RAM*

Comment: After a reboot, can you do ‛dmesg | grep sde‛ and show the results?

Comment: Eventually yes, I'm still waiting for some ideas from others that may not require a reboot.

Comment: Or try that without reboot, maybe your buffer is big enough.

Comment: It's a mix of the end_request errors as above, plus this:
    Buffer I/O error on device sde, logical block 0
    Buffer I/O error on device sde, logical block 1
    Buffer I/O error on device sde, logical block 2
    Buffer I/O error on device sde, logical block 3